# Datagrid in compact framework only shows about half the total number of rows?

Tags: c#, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm binding via datasource, the VisibleRowCount is stuck to 27 but there should be 50 entries (datatable.rowcount returns 50).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or could try to do to make all rows visible?

Comment: can you add some more detailed information or possibly some code? What makes you think DataTable.Rows.Count is 50? Are all changes (delets, inserts, updates) are committed to the table etc? Possibly Rows.Count also includes deleted rows.

Comment: Also, you may want to see that the data types you are binding to the Datagrid are valid. For example, I'm not sure if mobile supports images.

Comment: Well it's basically a copy+paste of another grid (with code) from a form and it's in a user control now, when it was in the form it worked fine... the code is unchanged.

Comment: The DataGrid is limited to 27 rows. That's all you get in the CompactFramework. Actually, No, just kidding, but obviously there must be a bug somewhere in your code. You'll have to post the code for anyone to tell you where it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisibleRowCount is just how many rows fit on the screen at once, not the total number of rows.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.visiblerowcount(v=vs.90).aspx

An excerpt:

> The number of rows **visible** in the viewport. The viewport is the
>   rectangular area through which the grid is visible. The size of the
>   viewport depends on the size of the System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
>   control; if you allow users to resize the control, the viewport will
>   also be affected.